# GCC 6.4 memory consumption is greater than GCC 4.9.3

Tags: gcc, memory-management

My program uses almost all STL memory structures. 
Memory consumption on `gcc-6.4` is greater than `gcc-4.9.3`.

Can somebody explain why?

Comment: How did you test? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Yes. There is some kind of bug in there somewhere.